# Overlapping two JButtons : Issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, overlap, jlayeredpane

Well sounds little weird, but I am trying to overlap two`JButtons` (here `jButton1` and `jButton2`).I am using NetBeans GUI builder for this.Nothing extraordinary,I am using JLayeredPane to make it possible.

```
 jLayeredPane1.add(jButton1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
```

Well it does overlap,but the `JButton` shows its self up,when Clicked by a mouse.
A screenshot will make it clear:

[image]

**(take highlighted portion as a mouse pointer)**

and

When the mouse pointer is clicked on the next `JButton`,it comes up,hiding the first JButton.
[image]

but,I **don't want** the second `JButton` to pop up(overlap 1st`JButton`) when clicked by a mouse.
How can i do this??Well, I think this may go critical.

Here is the code,if required:

```
public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame1() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLayeredPane2 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.setBounds(0, 40, 73, 23);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jButton1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.setBounds(40, 40, 73, 23);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jButton2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(98, 98, 98)
                    .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(139, 139, 139)
                    .addComponent(jLayeredPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(58, 58, 58)
            .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLayeredPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;


}
```

**UPDATE :**

If I am not clear, here i go again.

1) I don't want to make separate buttons,they should be overlapped .

2)Overlapping area may differ,the size of the button.

3)**The second JButton should not come above the 1st JButton,when clicked.(Solution for this,but not for how to layout the buttons.)**

4)There may be confusion,which button was clicked,but its ok for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does layout manager have to do with it?

@Patricia Shanahan has pointed out the problem with overlapping the buttons. One solution is to let the [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) do the work. In the example below, `butonPanel` has a centered `FlowLayout` by default. It adopts the preferred size of the buttons in any Look & Feel.

Addendum: Ah, you *want* the buttons to overlap but retain a stable *z*-order. Because rendering is controlled by the button's UI delegate, a subclass of `ButtonUI`, the effect is  Look & Feel dependent. For example, both `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` and `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`behave as you want, while many others do not. Absent creating your own delegate, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513), you might try to adapt the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513), which hides the button's and uses an overlaid image. Depending on the enclosing container's layout, either `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout(1, 0)` should work.

As an aside, don't let the GUI designer dictate your GUI design!

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075990/230513 */
public class LayoutTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("LayoutTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JPanel(){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 150); // content placeholder
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); // default: FlowLayout, centered
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Button1"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Button2"));
        f.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayoutTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider `OverlayLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513) among [other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13436787/230513) related approaches.

Comment: @joeyrohan: I've elaborated above.

Comment: `rendering is controlled by the button's UI delegate, a subclass of ButtonUI, the effect is Look & Feel dependent` +1.Well,that means there is no shortcut,I have to customize it myself?Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping the buttons creates confusion about which button was clicked. I suggest resizing the button that you want to be underneath so that the "hidden" part is no longer part of the button. That way, clicks in the common area will go only to the top button.

Comment: Also consider an alternate [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: `clicks in the common area will go only to the top button`
I want both the buttons to function as it is,if i resize the button,it will,still,come on the top.What I dont want to.

Comment: @joeyrohan: Fair question; I've elaborated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14075990/230513).

Comment: @trashgod are you not misunderstanding my question like last time?

Comment: @joeyrohan: Very likely, but I maintain that Patricia's observation is a useful caveat.

Comment: @trashgod in what way? Question is OutOfBond for that answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21864/discussion-between-trashgod-and-joey-rohan)

Comment: Not overlapping the buttons as far as the API is concerned puts you in total control. If you want a click in a certain area to go to both buttons, and know it will go to one of them, you can have your buttons support listening for clicks in a portion of their own area. The reduced size button underneath would listen to the top button for clicks in its logical area.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are adding the buttons to the same layer (the default one). You should number the layers. Hence for your code it would be something like this:

```
jLayeredPane1.add(jButton1, Integer.valueOf(0));
   
jLayeredPane1.add(jButton2, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Notice that you have to use the wrapper (`Integer` not `int`)

Comment: please format the code to make it easily readable (4 leading spaces)