# String and BufferedImage on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage

I am trying to display a string and a `BufferedImage` onto a `JFrame` that both come as output from a method. I am not able to separate the `String` from the image, therefore I need to add both to the `JFrame`.

Here is the code I have do far and nothing is displaying. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

```
String path = getUserInfo("abc123"); <-- method that returns a string and a buffered image
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(InstagramClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setVisible(true);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label, "icon", -1);
```

Comment: I don't think I understand.  Does the image contain the `String` or do you need to display it with the image?  You've not added anything to your frame, but instead showed an option pane

Comment: A method cannot "return a String and a BufferedImage". Methods can return one and only one thing. What exactly is not working? What errors are you seeing? Please clarify your question. Greatly.

Comment: MadProgrammer - I need to display the string with the image on a JFrame

Comment: Here is an example of what the getUserInfo() method returns:        Name: Kim Kardashian
BufferedImage@9b878c: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@b97081 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 150 height = 150 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
Bio: Twitter.com/KimKardashian
Website: http://kimkardashian.com

Comment: The code that I have right now only creates and shows a JFrame with nothing in it.

Comment: That is just a `toString()` result, you can't obtain an object from this string. Instead, the method should return the actual `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hovercraft Full Of Eels actually answered my question. I wanted to return both a String and  BufferedImage but now I know that is not possible. Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can render the string over the image using `drawString()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).

Alternatively, you can use `label.setText()` and rely on the label's horizontal & vertical alignment for positioning, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can use the label's `setText` method to supply a text value for the label.

You also need to "add" the label to the frame, or it won't display anything.

```
String path = getUserInfo("abc123"); <-- method that returns a string and a buffered image
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(InstagramClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
JFrame f = new JFrame();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
JLabel label = new JLabel("This is some text", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
f.add(label);
f.setVisible(true);
```