# set bottom of iconImagen in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlabel

I have a JLabel of 20x10 it has IconImage of 20, what i want is that the image set on bottom,

```
JLabel FONDO=new JLabel(Imagen("cas.png"));
       FONDO.setBounds(10, 30, 20, 10);
```

after i do mouseEvent the code change:

```
FONDO.setBounds(10, 30, 20, 20);
```

[image of my problem](http://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1260853_3310281011994_439079371_n.jpg)

[image]

the IconImagen is set on center... I needs it be on bottom

thanks for your advices!

Comment: search for vertical and horizontal Alignment in JLabel API, if without any success, then to try to set  [proper LayoutManager to JLabel, see answer by @Andrew Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18434145/714968)

Comment: Alignment don't have vertical alignment, and the LayoutManager use another JLabel, it doesn't work for me, thanks

Comment: I think you can to align both direction, search for setHorizontal/VerticalTextPosition or something similair or the same methods SwingConstant.Xxx

Comment: oooooh thanks yes you have the reason i add this code:
        fondo.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
it works perfectly!!

Comment: :-) .............................