# Putting JPanels In Corners?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to put a Panel filled with a couple of small components into the corner of my frame, but I'm not sure how to get it there. I'm guessing that I need to set a certain layout on my frame that allows me to reference that section of it somehow? I haven't found much help searching online. It would be great if someone could send me in the right direction.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2):

Try `javax.swing.OverlayLayout`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use gridbag layout on frame to put your panel on corner or any area depending on remaining elemnts to be placed on frame....
Or
You can set layout of frame to null
Frame.setLayout(null)
And use setbounds method on panel and add on frame....

Comment: JFrame has a `JLayeredPane` which it uses to display the content pane, menu bar and glass pane.  If your seriously considering a `null` layout, it would be better to simply to use the `JRootPane`'s layered pane directly

Comment: I already know that null layout is not good... GridBagLayout seems like what I want, I was hoping it would be something simple, however, like the way you position things with borderlayout.