# JLabel over another JLabel not working

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've been trying to put a JLabel over another one for my Roguelike. Unfortunaly, it doesn't seems to work. Here's my code so far :

```
public void updateDraw(int direction){
    int[] pos = Dungeon.getPos();

    for(int i=pos[1]-(DISPLAY_Y_SIZE/2) ; i<pos[1]+(DISPLAY_Y_SIZE/2) ; i++){
        for(int j=pos[0]-(DISPLAY_X_SIZE/2) ; j<pos[0]+(DISPLAY_X_SIZE/2) ; j++){
            labelGrid[i-(pos[1]-(DISPLAY_Y_SIZE/2))][j-(pos[0]-(DISPLAY_X_SIZE/2))].setIcon(tiles[Dungeon.getMapTile(i,j)].getIcon());      
        }
    }

    labelGrid[DISPLAY_Y_SIZE/2][DISPLAY_X_SIZE/2].add(character);

    this.repaint();
}
```

I've read some solutions to other problems, and they all do it by simply adding the JLabel to the other one. it doesn't work as intended here, any idea why ?

PS : I don't want to use a JLayeredPane for my JPanel.

Comment: What layout manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using a GridLayout

Comment: `GridLayout` will only allow you to allocate a single component to a given cell.  You could use a `GridBagLayout`, which will allow you to allocate multiple components to a single cell, but you will need to ensure that the components are added in the correct order

Comment: Try [`OverlayLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One Alternative

Don't create your game environment using components (i.e. JLabels). Instead, you can paint all your game objects.

For instance, if you're doing something like:

```
JLabel[][] labelGrid = JLabel[][];
...
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(...);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
...
for(... ; ... ; ...) {
   container.add(label);
}
```

You could instead get rid of the labels all together, and also use `Images` instead of `ImageIcons`, then you can just paint all the images to a single component surface. Maybe something like:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    Image[][] images = new Image[size][size];
    // init images

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,/*  Crap! How do we know what location? Look Below */);
    }  
}
```

- [`Grapchics.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

So to solve this problem with the locations (i.e. the x and y, oh and the size also), we could use some good old OOP abstractions. Create a class that wraps the image, the locations, and sizes. For example

```
class LocatedImage {
    private Image image;
    private int x, y, width, height;
    private ImageObserver observer;


    public LocatedImage(Image image, int x, int y, int width, 
                                     int height, ImageObserver observer) {
        this.image = image;
        ...
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, observer);
    }
}
```

Then you can use a bunch of instances of this class in your panel. Something like

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    List<LocatedImage> imagesToDraw;
    // init images
    // e.g. imagesToDraw.add(new LocatedImage(img, 20, 20, 100, 100, this));

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        for (LocatedImage image: imagesToDraw) {
            image.draw(g2d);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }  
}
```

Once you have this concept down, there are many different possibilities.

- Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for some general ideas about painting.

Comment: Wow thanks dude, it works very well ! Never thought doing that this way, thanks a lot !